# TFT LCD tutorial?

Tags: lcd, glcd

I am not sure if it is a good question or not, but I want to start working on TFT LCDs.
I have good experience both on T6963 and KS0108, dot matrices, but zero experience on TFTs.

Can anyone give any link or tutorial (basic / professional) on this topic? What type of driver is suitable?

Comment: TFTs and STNs aren't different enough for you to worry about relearning everything.

Comment: Thanks! But there is a big difference. STNs are easily found as modules and very easy to setup but TFT modules are not that prevalent.  What scares me is that I need a driver IC for that ( that I am not sure if I would use one of those Renesa's or other parts ) and I know nothing about their theory. I searched google but there are few resources for this topic and those few are written in Chinese or awful english!

Comment: Sure, but that's not an intrinsic difference between TFT and STN. You can also find bare STN panels as well.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Which driver is the best or the easiest? does it need a separate back light?

Comment: Have you purchased a specific part? does it have a data sheet? ATMEL and Roenesa have good parts but let us know what is your need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good and handy module. The biggest advantage is its documentation and very strong library both for AVR and ARM: TFT01-5 
http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/50-tft-lcd-screen-module-tft0150-p-420.html

Answer (score 2):

This company has TFT modules and English datasheets.

http://www.crystalfontz.com/products/index-tft.html